# JScrollPane for JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

```
public class ERPFrame extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    Controller controller;
    DefaultTableModel dfm;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ERPFrame frame = new ERPFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ERPFrame() {

        controller = new Controller();
        dfm = new DefaultTableModel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1123, 730);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


        table = new JTable(dfm);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);


        table.setBounds(343, 30, 734, 638);

        contentPane.add(table, scrollPane);
    } //end of constructor
}
```

I'm trying to get a `JScrollPane` for my `JTable`, but without success. Anyone got any idea of what I'm doing wrong? I have tried like everything, and searched for the problem for like 3 hours. How could it be so hard to add a scroll pane?

Comment: See [*Adding a Table to a Container*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show)

Answer (score 1):

The `JTable` is already the `ViewPortView` component of the `JScrollPane`. Replace

```
contentPane.add(table, scrollPane);
```

with

```
contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

Also, don't use absolute positioning (`null` layout) - Use a layout manager instead. 
In the absence of a layout manager, the default size of the `JScrollPane`, along with every other component is `0 x 0` and will not appear. This forces you to specify the size and position of every component on the container.